# Where to initialize Firebase Admin SDK in Java REST API?

Tags: java, rest, firebase, jersey

I am developing a REST API using Java, with the Jersy. The REST API will be used by a Fluttervmobile app.

I have decided to use Firebase in my application. So the mobile app will use Firebase Authentication. However the Firebase functions are only to authenticate the user at the moment, all other data are in a MySQL database which is accessible via the REST API.

Now, I installed the Firebase Admin SDK according to this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

The below is the code to initialize the app

```
try
        {
            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream serviceAccount = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("xxxxxx.json");

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My problem is, in which class should put this code in? I can use the rest filter classes to validate the token sent by the Firebase and initialize it at the same time. However this means if I get 1M requests, Firebase will be initialized for 1M times!

How can I solve this matter?

Comment: FYI, I edited the question.  Backticks are not used to mark product names.  They're used to delimit bits of code.

Comment: @DougStevenson: OK, Thanks Doug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the Firebase Admin SDK just once per process per project that needs to be accessed.  If you have once process and one project to access, initialize it just once in that process, before it's first used.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, 2 things coming to my mind. First thing is, initialize it per user by creating a login method. So when he logs in the SDK will be initialized too. 1M logins = 1M initialization.

 Second is initialize it just once in the whole app. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: I don't understand.  The Admin SDK doesn't work "per-user".

Comment: @PeakGen so how do you solve this issue? in which class do you initialize it? since like this answer does not really answer the original question?